# Can I raise the same problem on different StackExchange websites, when I'm interested in different aspects?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-crossover

Suppose I have a problem P

- I have been working on the problem, I have found and implemented solution X, but I'm not sure how "good" it is. I believe I should post it to CodeReview
- I am also working on another solution Y which I think is better, but I have trouble implementing it. I believe I should post it to StackOverflow
- I am wondering if there isn't a better strategy to tackle the problem. I believe I should post it to Programmers

Those 3 questions would relate to the same problem yet they cover different aspects (of course there could be more or different aspects/target StackExchange websites, but let's consider those 3).

- To begin with I hope that my abstract example was good enough and that indeed, if taken individually, each of the 3 cases correspond to the right StackExchange website I have mentionned.
- Shoud I open 3 questions, one for each website ? Or try to merge the questions on a single website ? (I'd say that purely in terms of efficiency, posting on 3 websites is better as we reach specialized communities)
- Should I include references in each specific site to say that the same problem is also asked on a different StackExchange for different reasons ?

The question I had in mind is about denormalisation in MongoDB : I have a working solution, I have a better yet uncomplete solution, and then I have no idea how totally stupid or totally okay my solutions are.

Comment: The "Hot Meta Posts" link was cut off at the most excellent position in the title. (It reminds me of when I'm in

Comment: Let's not forget the basic requirement that each question should make sense on its own, in isolation from the other two.  Linking between questions for context is fine, and even encouraged, but it should not depend on this context.

Answer (score 57):

The way you've posed your three separate questions, yes; they would be on-topic on all three sites, and yes, you could potentially post them on all three sites.

That said, I see a number of possible issues.

1. Your use of the terms "good" and "better."  There is no such thing as "good" or "better;" there is only that which best meets your functional and non-functional requirements.  You are the one most qualified to judge that.
2. "Strategy" sounds suspiciously like a question about software patterns.  There is a long history on Programmers of people asking "What is the best software pattern to use on this," as if there is some prepackaged solution waiting on some shelf somewhere that solves every possible computing problem.  There isn't.
3. Before you ask your "fix my broken code" question on Stack Overflow, you should first have made an attempt to [troubleshoot it with a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  Failing that, you need to *state your problem clearly* and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
4. There is always some overlap between the sites.  If your questions are closely related, it might still be better to combine the questions into a single post.

If you can overcome those potential issues, your questions are welcome on all three sites.  Code Review [has excellent advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking "good" questions there.

Comment: Thanks for those reminders about potential issues. Yes, I might have used "strategy" because I have recently taken a class about patterns, and I'm probably a bit too excited about reusing some. But you're right that really depends on requirements and specificity of the context. I'll try to remember all that when I write the questions. In the end you still seem to more in favor of combining them, but it's not really clear.

Comment: One question that can be customized (and is relevant on) three different sites is very rare.

Comment: @Cyril, I'd say the thing to keep in mind is not to ask what is "good" or "better," not to ask about "patterns" and "strategies," but to give a clear and specific description of what you are trying to do and ask how to achieve it. As Robert says, there is no such thing as a generic "best," only what works for you. Don't make people guess at what that is when writing an answer.

Answer (score 18):

I don't see any problem with cross-posts in general, as long as each post is appropriate and of good quality.  As a courtesy to other users who triage and answer your questions, **please declare your cross-posts** with mutual links, though.  I am much more annoyed by undeclared cross-posts.

It's pretty rare for a question to be well suited to three sites.  In your case, it sounds like asking for a review of a working solution X on Code Review and asking for help with solution Y on Stack Overflow make sense.  I would refrain from asking for more ideas on Programmers, because there is a possibility that a better strategy will be pointed out for you on Code Review.  If you already have a working solution and an almost-working solution, then abstracting and generalizing the description of the task to make it suitable for Programmers is like playing a game of charades.  It's much more efficient for just to talk about your concrete solution with full details.  (You may have a misconception that Code Review is restricted to tweaking your code.  Just mention in your question that you would consider a completely different strategy if it's better.)

Comment: I absolutely agree about cross-linking your posts. Not only will it help the people answering your questions gain more context, it will help future readers get more out of the posts.

Answer (score 6):

**Absolutely!**

Indeed, if you link them from each other it'll make for an even more interesting read than usual.

You may have to be prepared to defend yourself briefly from people spending more time in mistakenly accusing you of cross-posting than in actually paying attention to the question being asked.

Comment: Lightness changed name..?